# Solving the reaction-diffusion equation for a single species

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =k\Delta u+ru.
$$
Where all of the bounds are $0$.

Please help! Very new to PDE's and don't understand how to solve this. I know that I need to use separation of variables somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can change variables to arrive to the standard heat equation. Consider 
$$
v(x,t)=e^{-rt}u(x,t).
$$
If you multiply the original equation by $e^{-rt}$, you get
$$
\partial_t v=\partial_t u e^{-rt}-re^{-rt}u=e^{-rt}\Delta u=\Delta v
$$
which is the classical heat equation. Now you can solve by separation of variables easily.